# angular page becomes unresponsive after some time

Tags: angular, google-chrome

After some time (Maybe 20 mins) while not pushing anything on my published angular 8 website (using IIS 10), it becomes unresponsive.

The pointer on my mouse changes markers when I hover over buttons, but site gives no reactions at all when I push on anything.

Then when I change tab and goes back, the action suddenly happen without me pushing it again.

It happens over and over. The developer console doesn't give me any errors.

I'm using Chrome Version 89.0.4389.82

Anyone experienced this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak caused by observables, did you check the memory usage?

Comment: How can I check memory usage? Just looking at the task manager in windows performance and make sure the memery does not run too high, or can I do it smarter?

Comment: You can use the chrome profiler: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/allocation-profiler

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Subscription while making API calls, and unsubscribe those subscriptions on ngOnDestroy

Comment: I do use subscriptions and subscriptions from those.. I could look at all my subscriptions again, but doubt I will find any not unsubscribing in OnDestory. Whats my next move?

Comment: The only reason it can become slower over time is calls that are not unsubscribed. I would start checking those.

Comment: @MaartenDev After I do the same test on the stackoverflow page, I get the same result as on my webpage. With two different pcs, but same chrome build. Test is close browser open a new instance. Go directly to this page. Wait for it to turn off the screen (about 10 mins or my pc's) then afterwards wake it up by moving the mouse. Now page is dead on both pc's. I can't scroll and page doesn't update when I click "active, oldest or votes" buttons. But will react if I open a new tab and go back. So it has to be a chrome thing right? :/

Comment: How is the memory usage on your pc? @MichaelWinther

Comment: Only 4 GB on my windows server 2016, but only 44% used atm. Other one is lauptop with Windows 10 8 GB with currently 54% used. Don't think that's the issue :/ @MaartenDev

Comment: Could you ask someone else to confirm that they have the same issue? @MichaelWinther. Otherwise it may be caused by extensions